Solve linear system with non-invertible circulant matrix
I would like to solve a linear system $Ax = b$, where $A$ is given by the circulant matrix
$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1  & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & -1\\
-1 & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 &  0\\
0 & -1 & 1 & \ldots & 0 & 0 &  0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots  & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
(with $1$ on the diagonal, and $-1$ below the diagonal as well as in the top right corner).
I know that the determinant is $0$ so there is no solution, but is their some sort of "close enough solution", that for instance minimize $||Ax - b||$?
By the way what is the name of this matrix $A$?
I believe there is a connection between the eigendecomposition and Fourier, but I cannot remember...

To minimize $||A {\bf x} - {\bf b}||$, solve $A^\top A {\bf x} = A^\top {\bf b}$ for $\bf x$.

If you isolate the minus ones, the resulting matrix $M$ is a permutation matrix whose action is to "cycle" all elements to the right. That is, $M\cdot (x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)=(x_n,x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})$. So the present matrix is $I-M$ and acts as $(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)\to (x_1-x_n,x_2-x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}-x_n)$, i.e., it computes the cyclic differences of the input vector.

How to solve $A^T A x = A^\top b$ if $A$ is non-invertible? We have $det(A^T A) = det(A^T) * det(A) = 0$ right? So $A^T A$ is not invertible and the new linear problem also has no solution...

You can find the best approximation (assuming Euclidean distance) quite easily.
$$\operatorname{Im} A = \operatorname{span}(e_1-e_2, e_2-e_3,\ldots , e_{n-1}-e_n, e_n - e_1)$$
Obviously $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(e_k-e_{k+1})= e_1 - e_{n}$, so $e_n - e_1$ is linearly dependent on the other vectors.
But by the base exchange lemma you know that
$$e_1-e_2, e_2-e_3,\ldots , e_{n-1}-e_n, {\color{blue}{e_n}} \text{ is a basis of }\mathbb R^n$$
Especially $e_1-e_2, e_2-e_3,\ldots , e_{n-1}-e_n$ form a basis of $\operatorname{Im} A$.
Now, the vecor $e = \begin{pmatrix}1\\1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is orthogonal to $\operatorname{Im} A$.
Hence, the best approximation for $Ax = b$ in $\operatorname{Im} A$ is
$$b-\left\langle b, \frac e{||e||}\right\rangle \frac e{||e||} = b-\frac 1n\left(\sum_{k=1}^nb_k\right)e \in \operatorname{Im} A$$
In order to find a minimizing $x$ for a given $b$, you can create the $n\times (n-1)$-matrix
$$B = \begin{pmatrix}e_1-e_2, e_2-e_3,\ldots , e_{n-1}-e_n \end{pmatrix}$$
Note, that $B(B^TB)^{-1}B^T$ is the projector on $\operatorname{Im} A$.
Now, solve
$$B^TB x = B^Tb$$

First, denote ${\bf u} := \pmatrix{1 & \cdots & 1}^\top$, and notice that
$$\ker A = \operatorname{span}\{{\bf u}\} \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad \operatorname{im} A = \ker ({\bf u}^\top) = \left\{{\bf x} \,\bigg| \sum x_i = 0\right\} .$$ (To see these facts, recall that eigenvalues of the shift matrix characterized by $S{\bf x} := \pmatrix{x_2 & \cdots & x_n & x_1}$ are the $n$th roots of unity $\zeta_i$, each with multiplicity $1$, and our matrix is $A = {\bf 1}_n - S$, so its eigenvalues are $1 - \zeta_i$, exactly one of which is $0$, so $\dim \ker A = 1$. On the other hand, computing gives $A {\bf u} = {\bf 0}$ and ${\bf u}^\top A = {\bf 0}^\top$.)
We see that the equation $A {\bf x} = {\bf b}$ is soluble iff $\sum b_i = 0$. Either way, the vector in $\operatorname{im} A$ closest to $\bf b$ is the orthogonal projection ${\bf b}_0 := {\bf b} - \frac1n ({\bf u}^\perp {\bf b}) {\bf u}$ of $\bf b$ onto $\operatorname{im} A$ (i.e., along $\bf u$, since $\ker A \perp \operatorname{im} A$), and its distance from ${\bf b}$ is $||{\bf b}_0 - {\bf b}|| = \frac1{\sqrt n} |b_1 + \cdots + b_n|$.
Since $\dim \ker A = 1$, there is an entire (affine) line of vectors ${\bf x}$ such that $A {\bf x} = {\bf b}_0$, i.e., minimizing $||A {\bf x} - {\bf b}||$. Computing directly gives that the unique such vector in $\operatorname{im} A$ is the vector ${\bf x}_0$ whose $i$th component is
$$\frac1{2n} [(1 - n) b_{i + 1} + (3 - n) b_{i + 2} + \cdots + (n - 3) b_{i - 1} + (n - 1) b_i],$$
where the indices $j$ of the components $b_j$ of $\bf b$ are understood modulo $n$. Thus, the vectors $\bf x$ minimizing $A {\bf x} - {\bf b}$ are precisely those of the form
$${\bf x}_0 + t {\bf u}, \qquad t \in \Bbb R$$ (or $\Bbb C$ if we are regarding the matrices as complex).
Example ($n = 4$)
$${\bf x}_0 = \frac18 \pmatrix{
-3 b_2 - b_3 + b_4 + 3 b_1\\
-3 b_3 - b_4 + b_1 + 3 b_2\\
-3 b_4 - b_1 + b_2 + 3 b_3\\
-3 b_1 - b_2 + b_3 + 3 b_4}$$
I don't know of a name for the matrix A, but as Semiclassical pointed out in the comments,
$$A {\bf x} = \pmatrix{x_1 - x_n \\ x_2 - x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n - x_{n - 1}},$$
that is, the vector whose components are the differences of adjacent components of $\bf x$ (treating the first and last components as adjacent).
